# How to pass values from a dropdown list to the view in django

Tags: python, html, django

I have searched quite extensively for a clear answer to my problem but have not been able to find anything. I have am currently displaying the first 5 items from a database and want to add a feature that allows the user to toggle between ascending and descending order using the current rent value, but I am having trouble passing the value of the dropdown list to the views and altering the order of the table.

HTML file:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="GET" action="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<select name="dropdown">
  <option value="dsc">Descending</option>
  <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="order">
</form>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
                <th>Property Name</th>
                <th>Property Address 1</th>
                <th>Property Address 2</th>
                <th>Property Address 3</th>
                <th>Property Address 4</th>
                <th>Unit Name</th>
                <th>Tenant Name</th>
                <th>Lease Start</th>
                <th>Lease End</th>
                <th>Lease Years</th>
                <th>Rent</th>
            </thead>
    {% for data in list.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.property_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address1}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address2}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address3}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address4}}</td>
                <td>{{data.unit_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.tenant_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_start}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_end}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_years}}</td>
                <td>{{data.current_rent}}</td>
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from . import models
from .models import Stats
from django.views.generic import ListView,TemplateView,CreateView
# Create your views here.

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class StatsListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'list'
    model = models.Stats

    def get_queryset(self):

        first_five = Stats.objects.all().order_by('current_rent')[:5]
        return first_five

    def PageObjects(self,request):
        answer = request.GET['dropdown']
        if request.method == 'POST':
            if answer == 'dsc':
                Stats.objects.all().order_by('-current_rent')[:5]
            else:
                Stats.objects.all().order_by('current_rent')[:5]
```

Comment: Please post your code in a code block, not an image.

Comment: My mistake, first time posting something here. I have rectified the mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend sending your data with post:

```
{% block content %}
<form method="Post" action="" >
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<select name="dropdown">
  <option value="dsc">Descending</option>
  <option value="asc">Ascending</option>
</select>
    <input type="submit" value="Select">
</form>
<table id="myTable" class="tablesorter">
    <thead>
                <th>Property Name</th>
                <th>Property Address 1</th>
                <th>Property Address 2</th>
                <th>Property Address 3</th>
                <th>Property Address 4</th>
                <th>Unit Name</th>
                <th>Tenant Name</th>
                <th>Lease Start</th>
                <th>Lease End</th>
                <th>Lease Years</th>
                <th>Rent</th>
            </thead>
    {% for data in list.all %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{data.property_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address1}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address2}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address3}}</td>
                <td>{{data.property_address4}}</td>
                <td>{{data.unit_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.tenant_name}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_start}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_end}}</td>
                <td>{{data.lease_years}}</td>
                <td>{{data.current_rent}}</td>
            </tr>

    {% endfor %}
</table>

{% endblock %}
```

Views.py

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from . import models
from .models import Stats
from django.views.generic import ListView,TemplateView,CreateView
# Create your views here.

class HomeView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'index.html'

class StatsListView(ListView):
    context_object_name = 'list'
    model = models.Stats

    def get_queryset(self):

        first_five = Stats.objects.all().order_by('current_rent')[:5]
        return first_five

    def PageObjects(self,request):
       # Changes Begin Here: =========================>
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = YourForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                answer = form.cleaned_data['value']
       # Changes End Here: =========================>
            if answer == 'dsc':
                Stats.objects.all().order_by('-current_rent')[:5]
            else:
                Stats.objects.all().order_by('current_rent')[:5]
```

Comment: Hi Fady, sorry I'm new to development in django but where you've said YourForm what exactly are you referring to?

Comment: Hello Femi, look first you have to need to have forms.py and put it your forms and YourForm I was referring form name I recommend to watch this 2 video it will help you a lot in forms then back to your code :
1- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDuqObGbLnI&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=22
2- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hKoNbgVWyWc&list=PL6gx4Cwl9DGBlmzzFcLgDhKTTfNLfX1IK&index=23

Comment: So i have created a forms.py file but still not able to get it working. `from django import forms
from .models import Stats

class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Stats
        fields = ['current_rent']
        widgets = {'current_rent': forms.Select}`